# Python Dataframe list unique values based on some criterias

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this simple data set looks like this:

[image]

After importing it into a dataframe, I want to have a list of unique IDs that contains Type = 2. For instance, the desired output is:

ID
100654 100655

I think I need to use .groupby but I'm not sure how to make this happen. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need groupby to return values for one 'ID'.

Use the following with boolean indexing and `tolist`:

```
df[df.Type == 2].ID.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[100654, 100655]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict({'A': [100654,100654,100655,100655,100656,100656], 'B':[2,3,2,7,3,4]})

print (df[df['B'] == 2])
```

This will output:

```
        A  B
0  100654  2
2  100655  2
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use groupby as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict({'A': [100654,100654,100655,100655,100656,100656], 'B':[2,3,2,7,3,4]})
print df
'''
        A  B
0  100654  2
1  100654  3
2  100655  2
3  100655  7
4  100656  3
5  100656  4
'''

print 'group keys'
print df.groupby('B').groups.keys()

'''
group keys
[2, 3, 4, 7]
'''

print 'items related to key 2'
print df.groupby('B').get_group(2)['A']
'''
items related to key 2
0    100654
2    100655
Name: A, dtype: int64
'''

print "alternate method"
print df[df['B']==2]['A']
'''
alternate method
0    100654
2    100655
Name: A, dtype: int64
'''
```